# SSI querystring syntax

Tags: regex, query-string, ssi, shtml

I have a problem with a query string in SSI. Syntax isn't valid. The example URL is following:

```
www.site.com/index.shtml?firstID=100&secondID=104&thirdID=true 

<!--if expr="$QUERY_STRING = /^.*firstID=(.*)&.*/" --> 
   <!--#include virtual="page_1.shtml" -->
<!--#elif expr="$QUERY_STRING = /^.*firstID=(.*)&.secondID=(.*)&.thirdID=(.*)/" --> 
    <!--#include virtual="page_2.shtml" -->
<!--#endif -->
```

First 'IF' is correctly, Second is not.

Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 0):

There are `.`s in your second pattern before `secondID` and `thirdID` that are causing it to look for an extra character.  Remove those and the pattern should match:

`^.*firstID=(.*)&secondID=(.*)&thirdID=(.*)`